# How can I include stored values in a R Markdown table?

Tags: r, r-markdown

R Markdown beginner here. Is there a way I can include stored values in a R markdown table? For example, given that I have the value

```
x <- 20
```

How can I include x in a table like this:

```
|       Col1      |         Col2         |

|:----------------|:--------------------:|

| Row1            | [where x should be]  |
```

Just writing x obviously returns the letter after knitting and not the value needed.
Any help appreciated, cheers!

Comment: You can use a back-ticked inline expression "\`r x\`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example showing use of backticks.

````
---
title: "Variables in tables"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
x = 1
cell = 'hello world'
```

## R Markdown

First Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
`r cell`  | Content Cell
Content Cell  | `r x`
````